# How to make dynamic PDF form flowable across 2 pages in LiveCycle?

Tags: pdf, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I have a dynamic PDF form that is flowable on each page but not both.  By that I mean that the fields on the 2nd page won't move to the 1st page if there is available space.  How can I make the entire document flowable?  I am using Adobe LiveCycle ES2 Designer to create the form.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to have seperate pages I usually stick with one page and insert seperate subforms.
Make the Page and the subforms flowed (depending on the content use either top to bottom or western text).

Using this method allows you to create fragments from the subforms if required but also means that page flow will be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Select the Subform that you are working with.Then, in the object Panel, select Content as Flowed instead of Positioned.
Repeat the steps for the "Page" also.